# What is the point of "php app/console cache:warmup" in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

What purpose does running a warmup of the cache in symfony serve? My understanding is it doesn't actually create the entire cache directory structure under app/cache/env, you have to actually hit pages and endpoints for that to happen. In that case, what does it do?

We're running into a particular issue with caches ending up with bad permissions due to some legacy code and us having no realistic way of knowing that the entire cache has indeed been generated. I'd like to have a better understand of the cache mechanics, I don't do php or symfony development so my knowledge is limited to deployment and building artifacts in Bamboo.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

The warmup command is for running code that can simulate people hitting your pages.

The default cache warmup classes that are registered are:

- TemplatePathsCacheWarmer
- RouterCacheWarmer
- TemplateCacheCacheWarmer

You can write your own by extending the CacheWarmer class

[Extra information](http://blog.whiteoctober.co.uk/2014/02/25/symfony2-cache-warmup-explained/)